# Changing the default system-wide location of NuGet.config in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Is there any way to modify the default system-wide location of the NuGet.config file which points to ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config in Linux?

I tried modifying the XDG_DATA_HOME environment variable as is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) but it does not seem to have any effect.